# write to process standard in from file

Tags: linux, proc

On linux how do I send input to a while read loop inside of another terminal?
I am trying to run a read while loop the process`s some streamed data, that data is being streamed out of a node js process.

It be helpful to know how to do this on OpenBSD Linux and OSX

Answer (score 1):

Would a simple filesystem pipe/fifo work? I know it works on Linux and I would expect it to work on OpenBSD and Mac OS X as well.

```
mkfifo fifo
```

This creates a special file named 'fifo' with a type of 'p'. In one terminal:

```
echo "Hey, is this thing on?" > fifo
```

And in another terminal:

```
cat fifo
```

The text goes through the pipe.